# How can I turn this into a perfect cylinder

Tags: transforms, faces, loop

During modeling, I often find myself having this problem. How can I turn the following face loop into a perfect cylinder?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the *LoopTools > Circle*. Enable the *LoopTools* addon, select the bottom and top edges (or as you say, simply select the face loop), right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! Even with the face loop selected. I should add that you need to apply scale of the object first, otherwise it will turn into a distorted cylinder.

Comment: Upvote for the expressive action lines

Comment: @glades, you're right, I've edited

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos, thanks for noticing, it took me hours to make them look nice  :/